# How to make a bar plot in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, histogram

How can I make a histogram from my data? I mean, I know my samples that are for exmaple

```
s = [1,4,2,5,3]
```

Then I would like to have a plot such that first bar has height 1, second 4 and so on. So the number of bars must be equal to `len(s)`. So my hope is to get a histogram like

```
   #
 # #
 # ##
 ####
#####
```

but graphical. I tried to use matplotlib but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this works fine for me:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
s = [1,4,2,5,3]
plt.bar(range(len(s)), sorted(s))
plt.show()
```

For the barplot you need to provide two lists, first one that would set the x positions and then another for the y values on each y position.

For your example, the easiest way is to make a vector from 0 to the length of your array: `range(len(s))` and use this for the bar positioning, and you get this:

[image]

Comment: I tried that and it works in that special case. But when the list is ['106.84', '107.51', '107.55', '107.28', '107.57', '106.75', '107.33', '107.46', '107.38', '107.6'] the y-axis numbers are not in increasing order.

Comment: Couldn’t you just provide the sorted list? See the updated reply

Comment: I tried to plot the list `[106.84, 107.51, 107.55, 107.28, 107.57, 106.75, 107.33, 107.46, 107.38, 107.6]` and it started to work after I converted strings to float. The scale of y-axis seems to be too big, 0 to 110 so it is hard to compare bars.

Comment: That you can change with the ylim function